# call WinAPI without unsafe block

Tags: rust

I just started to learn Rust and would like to know whether it is possible to call WinAPI functions without unsafe?

```
extern crate libc;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        libc::funcs::extra::kernel32::GetCurrentProcessId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

No, it is impossible, because they are direct bindings to functions in external C libraries, just like almost everything else in `libc` crate. It may be not obvious with functions like `GetCurrentProcessId()`, but these functions *are* unsafe because there is a lot of them which take and return raw pointers and null-terminated strings.

In order to call them without `unsafe` there should be an appropriate safe wrapper, just like for any other C library. There is no such wrapper yet, as far as I know. But you can write one just for the subset of WinAPI functions you need, it shouldn't be too hard. You can find more details on how to write safe wrappers for external libraries [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-ffi.html) and [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-unsafe.html).